# How is php database asset control done?

Tags: php, pdo

in the code you see below, I want to check for existence in the database and if there is no data in the same id's, I want to save data to the database. I cannot compare $product['p_id'] with $id because the data from the database is returned as an array. In the if line I made below, it saves the data without fulfilling the condition. Can someone help me please ?

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM basket');
$query->execute();
$product = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
$piece = isset($_POST['piece']) ? $_POST['piece'] : null;
$user = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : null;


if($product['p_id'] != $id) {
    $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO basket SET
    b_piece = ?,
    p_id = ?,
    u_id = ?
    ');

    $result = $query->execute([
        $piece, $id, $user
    ]);
 } else {
  }
```

Comment: First get the data from `$_POST` array, then add a WHERE statement to your SELECT query (`WHERE p_id = ?`) so you only fetch the row(s) with that `p_id`. If you get results back, it exists. If no results are returned, then that id doesn't exist in the db.

Comment: $product wont have a key 'p_id'. fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows. So if($product['p_id'] != $id) will be always true